# DAX-Power BI bring unique values from a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm currently trying to create a new column and bring the unique values from column 3( the ones that are not on column 1 or column 2). Could you help to create a DAX formula to pull this info?

The data that i want to reach is at column 4

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIlEl.png)

Comment: Could you add what output you expect? I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Sure @Marco_CH, i change the original pic, adding  what i expect from the dax formula. The formula should bring the data that is on column 4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.